# Javascript - Odds of ID Collision

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

Just curious what the odds of ID collision is for the 'uniqueID' variable below:

```
    var uniqueID = new Date().getTime() + '-xxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0,
            v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
```

I realize I can use a GUID to create a "globally unique" ID.  However, for our purposes, "unique enough" may satisfy our requirements.  I'd just like to know mathematically what the likelihood of collision is with this approach.

Comment: You are appending a time stamp - `new Date().getTime()`. I don't think ID collision will occur.

Comment: Should there be some `y`'s in `xxxxxxxx`?

Comment: Timestamp in milliseconds is going to be unique and so there won;t be any collision

Comment: @mohamedrias theres probably a chance of collision

Comment: and there's the crux: time stamp in milliseconds. If you generate two within the same millisecond, the odds of them colliding are extremely low, but non-zero. Math.random() is supposedly uniform, so it's simply the odds of Math.random() colliding, times the number of Math.random() calls.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans you should add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Your time stamp is in milliseconds, so if you generate two within the same millisecond, the odds of them colliding are low, but non-zero.

Now, normally with Math.random() being supposedly uniform, the odds of a collision is simply the odds of two Math.random() calls colliding, times the number of Math.random() calls you're performing.... but you added something "clever" that actually has disastrous effects on the odds:

```
r = Math.random() * 16; // good: a random float between 0 and 16
r = Math.random() * 16 | 0; // bad: a random int between 0 and 16
```

That `|0` converts the incredibly rich floating point random number into a 32 bit integer, losing all those lovely bits that would prevent collision.

I have no idea why, but you've added it, and it make the odds of collision higher: at every step, the odds of a collision are now a fairly *likely* 1/16, so the total odds are (1/16) to the power of "the number of `x`es in your string".

Basically they're needlessly high and I'd reject this generator. It's rather weird, especially since you can use a few straight up Math.random(), or if you want true uniqueness, use an *actual* uniqueness criterium paired with a sequential id generator like

```
var nextid = (function(id) {
  id = id || 0;
  return function() { return id++; };
}(firstIdToUse)); // <- optional seed value
```

There, now your uniqueness is limited purely by the Number type in JavaScript. That's about 2^53 unique numbers to work with. And should you need to seed it, that's trivially set.

Comment: The odds are not `1/16` per ID, they are `1/16` per hex digit in ID, represented as `x`; there is nine of them, for a total of `4*9` bits, giving the odds as `1/68719476736` per call. The why is obvious: the random number is a digit, so it has to be integral. This is not as good as `1/2^56`, but it is easy to adjust with adding more digits. Also, the OP might have reason not to use the counter IDs, for example several independent agents creating IDs at the same time.

Comment: @Amadan thanks, that actually answers my question.  if you post it as an answer, i will accept.

Comment: @Amadan: yes, that's literally what I said? `the total odds are (1/16) to the power of "the number of xes in your string"`. VinnyD asked about the odds of collision, which this answer describes; the rest is commentary based on "why settle for "unique enough" when "actually unique" is better, with less code?"

Comment: The answer itself is fine. I'm reacting to 'but you added something "clever" that actually has disastrous effects on the odds' and '...losing all those lovely bits that would prevent collision'. He does strip down to 4 bits per random call, but makes it up by stringing several digits - so I was very puzzled why you think `Math.random() * 16` is good, but a number of `Math.random() * 16 | 0` is bad. You can have stronger entropy with latter, with enough `x`s. And I've demonstrated why "better" is relative, and can change with design requirements.

Comment: From a computation persepctive, collisions of two successive `Math.random()*16` calls are far less likely than two successive calls of `Math.random()*16`. If your goal is to avoid collisions, then casting a 64 bit float in which pretty much all the bits are relevant to a 32 bit integer in which only four bits ever matter, is a weird thing to do, and anyone who asks about "what the odds of collision are" but shows this code, is probably not aware this is what they're doing. If they *intentionally* forced a 32 bit int with 4 meaningful bits, they'd already understand the probabilities involved.